Getting the Client ID of an app that uses Google Sign In
We are adding a Sign In with Google option to our app. I'm following the steps listed here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth#php in order to verify the integrity of the ID token sent from the app to our server. However there is this line:
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]); 

and it says that this is "the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend".
The app has been created in the Firebase console. Where do I find this Client ID?

Perhaps the answers in this question can help out:
Where do i get the web client secret in firebase Google Login for android?
It should be in the web SDK configuration in the firebase console

Thanks I found it in the json file as one of the thread messages mentioned.
